# Hibernation simple direct mapping

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, annotations

I have 2 tables employees and orders: [Console screens_before execusion](http://imageshack.us/g/689/screenshotfrom201306021v.png/)
Now i'm trying to map list collection to get all orders of each employee. My mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees", schema = "public")
public class Employees implements java.io.Serializable {

         /**
          *
          */
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1885071569771542035L;
         private short employeeid;
         //...

         private List<Orders> ordersList;
         @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employees")
         public List<Orders> getOrders() {
                 return ordersList;
         }

         public void setOrders(List<Orders> orders) {
                 this.ordersList = orders;
         }
```

.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders", schema = "public")
public class Orders implements java.io.Serializable {

         /**
          *
          */
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 405644896073449066L;

         private short orderid;
         //...

         private Employees employees;

         @ManyToOne
         public Employees getEmployees() {
                 return employees;
         }

         public void setEmployees(Employees employees) {
                 this.employees = employees;
         }

         public Orders() {
         }

         public Orders(short orderid) {
                 this.orderid = orderid;
         }
```

But unfortunately I'm getting none. I've been trying to detect sql queries to database, and i think hibernate creates new column: [sql result](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/689/screenshotfrom201306021v.png/)

It probably need to refer to:

```
orders0_.employeeid as employeeid1_0_,
```

not to

```
orders0_.employees_employeeid as employees15_1_0_,
```

But I don't know how to force him to do it. (I'm using postgresql)

Comment: Post text instead of images. Reduce it to the minimal, relevant part. And post your code here, not at pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify any name for the join column used to map your association, so Hibernate uses the default one, as specified in the JPA specification: `employees_employeeid`. To use `employeeid` instead, you must tell Hibernate: it can't guess it:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employeeid")
public Employees getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}
```

Also, an instance of Employees is a single employee, so the class should be named Employee, and not Employees. Same for Orders. And same for the property `order.employees`, which implies that the order has several employes, although it has only one. The property should be named `employee`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employeeid")
public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}
```

Comment: I have tried @JoinColumn earlier, but i suspect that as a result of few other problem it didn't work then, now I've added and it is fine, thank you ;)